# Trouble translating a SQL statement

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am attempting to translate a SQL CASE statement but am running into some problems and was hoping I could get a hand.  Here is the statement:

```
,SUM(CASE WHEN [Gads].[GadsEventTypeCode] IN ('D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'DP', 'PD', 'DM', 'D4')
    THEN [Allocation].[AllocatedEnergyMwh] ELSE 0 END / 
    CAST([Unit].[NetDependableCapacity] AS FLOAT)) AS Hrs_Derate
```

This is what I come up with but get "lost in translation":

If `[Gads].[GadsEventTypeCode]` equals `'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'DP', 'PD', 'DM', 'D4'`
then `Hrs_Derate` equals the sum of:
`[Allocation].[AllocatedEnergyMwh] / [Unit].[NetDependableCapacity]`
 else `Hrs_Derate` equals zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three elements that you need to translate:

1. CASE statement - this can be [handled with a ternary expression](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38264/How-to-Create-T-SQL-CASE-Statements-With-LINQ-To-S), e.g.,  `(cond) ? trueval : falseval`
2. IN clause - there is the LINQ `.Contains` operator which can check if an element is contained inside an array.
3. Casting - the cast operator I believe is handled via the same methods in `System.Convert`.

Armed with these three translation rules, you would need something like this (untested):

```
var types = new [] { "D1", "D2", "D3", "DP", "PD", "DM", "D4" };

Hrs_Derate =
    ((types.Contains(gads.GadsEventTypeCode) ? allocation.AllocatedEnergyMwh : 0)
    / (Convert.ToFloat(unit.NetDependableCapacity))).Sum()
```

Comment: @ mellamokb - Thank you for your help, especially about the .Contains operator.  I will definitely make use of it.  However, before I can translate the SQL into LINQ, I have to understand what exactly the statement is saying.  That is what I am trying to wrap my head around.  Is the if statement that I created above a correct translation of what the SQL statement is saying?

Comment: Yes, you have a rough idea of the code.  Note that `GadsEventTypeCode` could be different for each row, so it's not so much calculating *either* the sum of `Allocation.AllocatedEnergyMwh / Unit.NetDependeableCapacity` or `0`, but it's sort of "looping" through the rows and saying, if this row has a type of `D1, D2, ...` , then add energy / capacity to a running total, else add 0.  Among all the rows in the table, some will match the type code and contribute a value toward the sum, and some will not match and thus contribute 0 toward the sum.

Comment: @ mellamokb: Ah, OK.  That makes sense.  Thank you very much for the clarification. You have been a great help!  I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

You're not quite there.

"If [Gads].[GadsEventTypeCode] **equals** 'D1', 'D2', 'D3', 'DP', 'PD', 'DM', 'D4'"

This checks for `GadsEventTypeCode` being *any* of the listed values.

"then Hrs_Derate equals the sum of:
 [Allocation].[AllocatedEnergyMwh] / [Unit].[NetDependableCapacity]"

That covers the rest.  The bit about `ELSE 0` causes it to ignore rows that don't meet the `GadsEventTypeCode` condition, i.e. adding zero doesn't effect the `SUM`.  A `NULL` would work as well.